# how to set the svg shape between two div tags without leaving any empty space?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have no idea how to set the SVG image to the top where I have kept the tag between two div tags. And there seems to be a gap.

I tried this code of HTML and CSS.

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L14.1,229.3C28.2,235,56,245,85,256C112.9,267,141,277,169,250.7C197.6,224,226,160,254,154.7C282.4,149,311,203,339,218.7C367.1,235,395,213,424,213.3C451.8,213,480,235,508,240C536.5,245,565,235,593,218.7C621.2,203,649,181,678,170.7C705.9,160,734,160,762,176C790.6,192,819,224,847,250.7C875.3,277,904,299,932,266.7C960,235,988,149,1016,101.3C1044.7,53,1073,43,1101,32C1129.4,21,1158,11,1186,42.7C1214.1,75,1242,149,1271,181.3C1298.8,213,1327,203,1355,176C1383.5,149,1412,107,1426,85.3L1440,64L1440,0L1425.9,0C1411.8,0,1384,0,1355,0C1327.1,0,1299,0,1271,0C1242.4,0,1214,0,1186,0C1157.6,0,1129,0,1101,0C1072.9,0,1045,0,1016,0C988.2,0,960,0,932,0C903.5,0,875,0,847,0C818.8,0,791,0,762,0C734.1,0,706,0,678,0C649.4,0,621,0,593,0C564.7,0,536,0,508,0C480,0,452,0,424,0C395.3,0,367,0,339,0C310.6,0,282,0,254,0C225.9,0,198,0,169,0C141.2,0,113,0,85,0C56.5,0,28,0,14,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
      <div class="form">
        <div class="header">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:#2ed573;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.form{
  background:#1e90ff;
  width:200px;
  height:50vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

and output is like this:
[image]
and I don't want the empty space above that SVG white image.

Comment: That's defined by the `viewbox` – does changing the value to `viewBox="0 21 1440 320"` achieve your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

- `.main` is filling the full viewport and `.main { justify-content: center }` centers its content vertically.
- The SVG is only `320` tall, so on larger screens or portrait layouts it moves down vertically exposing the green background of `.main` above itself.

**Solution**

By default *Flexbox layout* property `justify-content` is `flex-start`, which is essentially what you want. Remove `justify-content: center` from `.main` and take it from there.

Optionally, you can move `.form` to a preferred location using `margin` or make `.main` `relative` and move `.form` `absolute` inside main using property `inset` or properties `top, right, bottom, left`.

**Snippet**

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:#2ed573;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
/*  justify-content:center; /* REMOVE */
  flex-direction:column;
}
.form{
  background:#1e90ff;
  width:200px;
  height:50vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L14.1,229.3C28.2,235,56,245,85,256C112.9,267,141,277,169,250.7C197.6,224,226,160,254,154.7C282.4,149,311,203,339,218.7C367.1,235,395,213,424,213.3C451.8,213,480,235,508,240C536.5,245,565,235,593,218.7C621.2,203,649,181,678,170.7C705.9,160,734,160,762,176C790.6,192,819,224,847,250.7C875.3,277,904,299,932,266.7C960,235,988,149,1016,101.3C1044.7,53,1073,43,1101,32C1129.4,21,1158,11,1186,42.7C1214.1,75,1242,149,1271,181.3C1298.8,213,1327,203,1355,176C1383.5,149,1412,107,1426,85.3L1440,64L1440,0L1425.9,0C1411.8,0,1384,0,1355,0C1327.1,0,1299,0,1271,0C1242.4,0,1214,0,1186,0C1157.6,0,1129,0,1101,0C1072.9,0,1045,0,1016,0C988.2,0,960,0,932,0C903.5,0,875,0,847,0C818.8,0,791,0,762,0C734.1,0,706,0,678,0C649.4,0,621,0,593,0C564.7,0,536,0,508,0C480,0,452,0,424,0C395.3,0,367,0,339,0C310.6,0,282,0,254,0C225.9,0,198,0,169,0C141.2,0,113,0,85,0C56.5,0,28,0,14,0L0,0Z"></path>
    </svg>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```